# Windows 10: command window does not close, but closes in Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cmd, subprocess, windows-10

i'm using windows 10 and trying to start an exe in diffrent folders sequentially. The idea is to use popen from subprocess and wait for the process to finish. The problem is, that the window does only close if I click on it or hit a key. On a windows 7 machine however the window is closing and subprocess.wait() finishes.

```
import os
import subprocess

for path in ["C:\tmp\", "C:\tmp2\"]:
    os.chdir(path)
    mywindow = subprocess.Popen(["my.exe",
                                #stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                #stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                #stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                #shell=True, 
                                creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,                         
                                env=dict(os.environ, **{"test":"AUTO"}))
    mywindow.wait()
```

I used `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, because I need to be able to start my.exe multiple times and be able to read the output on another console. But in some cases I want to wait for my process to end.

**Update:**

After eryksuns comment I'm pretty sure that this more of a windows problem than a python one.

On Windows 7 "my.exe" exits and `wait()` returns afterwards. On windows 10 however, I have to click somewhere on the screen or press any key, in order to close the console window "my.exe" opens. Afterwards the `wait()`returns. Disabeling the cmd quick edit mode had no effect.

Comment: Do you mean "my.exe" creates a new console as requested, but in Windows 10 `wait()` doesn't return (i.e. the "my.exe" process doesn't exit) until you manually click on the window or close it? Check whether the console's default properties or "my.exe" properties have quick-edit mode enabled, and if so try disabling it.

Comment: Thanks eryksun. I disabled quick edit mode on the console "my.exe" opens. Without an effect. You are right. Its more of a windows than python problem. On Windows 7 "my.exe" exits and `wait()` returns afterwards. On windows 10 however, I have to click somewhere on the screen or press any key, in order to close the console window "my.exe" opens. Afterwards the `wait()`returns

Comment: Having to click or press a key to continue implies the program is either blocked on console I/O or a `WaitForSingleObject` call on the console input buffer. For the former, it could be that the console is in mark mode for selecting text, in which case console writes will block (i.e. not complete and return until mark mode is exited). With quick edit enabled that happens automatically with a stray mouse click. In the new console in Windows 10, Shift+Arrows or Ctrl+A also selects text.